# Change cursor over HTML5 Canvas when dragging the mouse

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have made a paint brush type of application using the Canvas Tag . I wanted that when the mouse is on the canvas the Cursor Changes ,

```
<canvas id="draw" style="cursor: url(image/pencil.cur)">
```

I have accomplished this but i cant figure out how shall i change the cursor while I Drag the mouse for drawing the image

Comment: Note that you should [avoid putting your CSS in with your HTML](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/DMBWC/1/  This example shows that it does not work if you have selectable text on the page. When you drag across the canvas in my example above, it still turns into a text-select cursor.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the `:active` CSS pseudo-class to change the cursor when the mouse button is down over the element:

```
#draw:active { 
    cursor: url(image/pencil.cur);
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nXv63/**

Comment: Never thought of using :active on non clickable elements... cool :)

Comment: **Comment by [hydrarulz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/151244) (rejected edit):** You also need to add `:focus` for Chrome. It does not work in some cases with only `:active`. Replace `#draw:active {` by `#draw:active, #draw:focus {`.

Comment: It doesn't work when the canvas is inside a div that has text in it: http://jsfiddle.net/DMBWC/202/

Comment: @FernandoEscher: seems to be a bug in WebKit, Firefox is fine.  Bug filed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105355.

Comment: Apparently still a bug in webkit. I am seeing the same problem. I've got a canvas with cursor: crosshair; and also set both :active and :focus, and it switches to normal text selection cursor in webkit, but stays crosshair in Firefox (as of March, 2013).

Comment: Instead of CSS, using preventDefault() in mouseDown works, at least in Chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805318/when-i-click-on-a-canvas-and-drag-my-mouse-the-cursor-changes-to-a-text-selecti

Comment: @BrianSlesinsky's comment needs to not be buried. Pretty much the only thing that worked for me in Chrome.

Comment: Just a note that the WebKit/Chrome bug was fixed at some point, but slipped by me.  The last few versions of Chrome seem fine.

Answer (score 6):

For any one still looking for a solution to this webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105355, this is what I did.

I added this property to the body element to make all text unselectable in my page and that's it.

```
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;

    -webkit-user-select: none;

    -moz-user-select: none;

    user-select: none;
}
```

The problem is that if you really need an element to be selectable, you will have to change its CSS to make it so.

Comment: +1, while not really a viable solution, an interesting workaround nonetheless.  There seem to be a lot of people experiencing this issue, it would make a lot of sense for as many of you as possible to add a comment to the bug report so that developers can see the importance of fixing it.

Comment: that worked for me. I set those properties on the canvas container and was good to go!

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches I can think of for this, one of which might accomplish what you want:

1. Use some JavaScript to change the cursor, along the same lines as this jQuery fragment:

   ```
   $('canvas#draw').css('cursor', 'url(image/another-cursor.cur)');
   ```

   If you were to use that in the event for when the mouse button is pressed, and restore the original when it is released, I imagine that would have the exact effect you desire.
2. Draw the "cursor" on the canvas itself, and have it track the mouse position on the canvas. This way, you could draw a Photoshop-style circle (etc) to indicate where the drawing is going to take place. I'm not sure how performance might be with this approach (I've not tried it), but I imagine it ought to be fine. Just use the event which is fired on mouse move for the canvas, which is presumably what you're already using to track where the paint ought to be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/DMBWC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add a "dragging" class to the canvas while the dragging action is on (and remove it on mouseUp)

Then add this style:

```
canvas {cursor: default;}
canvas.dragging {cursor: crosshair;}
```

Comment: Even this didn't work for me! It still changes to the selection cursor.