# Change cursor over HTML5 Canvas when dragging in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, canvas, drag

I was looking at how to change the cursor over an HTML5 canvas when dragging the mouse...
Came across this: [Change cursor over HTML5 Canvas when dragging the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945874/change-cursor-over-html5-canvas-when-dragging-the-mouse)

seemed logical that an :active pseudo-selector would do the trick...

When I used it on my page, however, the cursor set by the rule in the :active pseudo-selector was ignored, instead showing the text selection cursor.

In firefox, this behavior is not present - it obeys the cursor property I set.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nXv63/466/) to demonstrate the behavior.

Any idea how to fix this in chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXv63/466/)**

Add the following for Chrome to turn off text selection while dragging and dropping.

```
document.onselectstart = function(){ return false; }​
```

This has been answered a few times,

[chrome sets cursor to text while dragging, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745028/chrome-sets-cursor-to-text-while-dragging-why)

[Click and Drag Cursor in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388284/click-and-drag-cursor-in-chrome)

Comment: maybe you shall clarify the fact that document is indeed the canvas object not the document global variable. so the correct thing to say would be canvas.onselectstart = function() { return false; }